# How to Optimize below Neo4J query

Tags: neo4j

I have two tables i.e. 
1) Places data - 2.4 Million records 
2) Office data - 40 thousand records

I have a Neo4J query that takes 3 inputs from the users through a UI and outputs the results after calculating distance between them using Latitude/Longitude information at the run time. I want to calculate the distance in the run-time only

Below is the query:-

```
MATCH (c:places), (c2:office)
  WHERE c2.office_id = {office}
  AND c2.city = {city}
  AND c.category = {category}
  RETURN c.places_id as place_name, c.category as Category, 
c.sub_category as Sub_Category, distance(c.location, c2.location) 
as Distance_in_meters order by distance(c.location, c2.location) LIMIT 50
```

Above query taken some 10-15 seconds to output the results on the UI, which is a bit annoying. Can you please help to optimize the performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next query:

```
MATCH (c:places), (c2:office {office_id: YourOffice, city: YourCity, category: YourCategory}) RETURN c.places_id as place_name, c.category as Category, 
c.sub_category as Sub_Category, distance(c.location, c2.location) 
as Distance_in_meters ORDER BY Distance_in_meters ASC/DESC LIMIT 50
```

And decide how order the results: ASC or DESC